# pull "firstword secondword" from text file into single char array

Tags: c++

I am getting a segmentation fault: core dumped error when I am reading in players file..
I am trying to add both "firstname lastname" to the player struct. I am trying to access the "0th" people and increment their name because i need both first and last, i cant simply fin >> people[i].name in a simply for loop as i do for the card value (not shown) "heart two 2" for example

```
// deck of cards
// below are initializations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//globals
const int maxCards = 52;

//Structs
struct card {
    char suit[8];
    char rank[6];
    int cvalue;
    char location;
};

struct player {
    char name[];
    int total;
    card hand[];
};

//program
int main()
{
    char tempfName[100];
    char templName[100];

    //create struct array(s)
    card deck[52];
    card shuffledDeck[52];
    player people[4];

    //set defalt values
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        strcopy(people[i].name,"first last");
    }

    //open player names file
    ifstream fin2;
    string fin2Name;

    //get file name from user
    cout << "Enter player file name...(Players.txt)" << endl;
    getline(cin,fin2Name);
    fin2.open(fin2Name.c_str());

    //check if Players.txt opens correctly
    if(!fin2.good())
    {
        cout << "Error with player file!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int j =0;
        //fin2 >> people[j].name;  //prime file
        while(fin2.good())
        {
            //find the length
            int index =0, length=0;
            while(tempfName[length] != '\0')
            {
                length++;
            }
            //now add space after first name
            tempfName[length] = ' ';
            length++;
            while(templName[index] != '\0')
            {
                tempfName[length] = templName[index];
                length++;
                index++;
            }
            tempfName[length]='\0';
            int counter =0;
            while(templName[counter] != '\0')
            {
                people[0].name[counter] = templName[counter]; //testing program on "0th" people
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow wont copy over my formatting

Comment: suppose it's strcpy and not strcopy.  Don't you want to use std::string ?

Comment: @mattmowris: it looks like you made the mistake of using tabs for  indentation (in some places, at least) - if you stick to using spaces for indentation (as nature intended) then you won't have this problem.

Comment: yea ive been using tabs..

Comment: Time to stop doing that then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your struct, `name[]` and `hand[]` are of undetermined size.  It's hence difficult to read anything into them.

Then, once you've opened the stream, you're trying to determine the length of the unitianalized `tempfName[]`.  This ain't no good:  you're not sure it's null terminated and you'll go out of bounds !  This is the origin of your segfault.

Consider initalizing these by declaring them as:

```
char tempfName[100]{};
char templName[100]{};
```

Once this is fixed, your code still loops forever on `while (fin2.good())` without reading anything, and bravely adding one whitespace to tempfName until you're out of bound.

Now suppose you'd fix all this, set a length to your `name` and undcomment your stream reading `fin2 >> people[j].name;`  you'd still have a very risky situation:  if the data would be longer that what you've foresseen, it would be truncated and the name wouldn't have a terminating '\0'.

**Recommendation 1:**

Consider using std::string  instead of char[] whenever you consider storing a string.  Example:

```
struct player {
    string name = "first last" ;   // initialisation value: no strcpy() needed !! 
    int total;
    card hand[5];  // length ?
};
```

**Recommendation 2:**

Loop using your stream reading as loop condition:

```
    while (fin2 >> people[j].name) { ///!!!
         ...
         j++;  // don't foget to increment your counter 
    }
```

However be carefull,  because the `>>` will read one string at a time, the string ending at first whilespace (so only firstname).

If you adopt recommendation 1, it would be easy to write:

```
    while (fin2 >> tempfName >> templName) {  ///!!!
        people[j++].name = tempfName + " " + templName; 
     }
```

which should perform pretty muchthe same thing that your loop, but with far less instructions and risks.

**Recommendation 3:**

If your number of players is fixed,  define the max constant and use a for instead of a while to read your data:

```
 const int max_player = 4; 
 player people[max_player];
 ... 
 for (j=0; j<max_player && (fin2 >> people[j].name); j++)  // instead of the former while
```

If your limit of 4 was arbirary, consider using vectors.  But that's another story for the moment.

Comment: tempfName is initialized..tempfName[100];

Comment: @mattmowris: no - that's not *initialisation*, that's just a *declaration*. To initialise you can use the suggestion above, or e.g. `char tempfName[100] = "";`

Comment: @mattmowris it's true that {} looks useless.  However it ensures default values (zeros) in the char array.

Comment: oh i see! i hav eto go with recommendation 2, c-style strings are a requirement on this project. thakns so much for your information..how would i go about pulling both names with >>? this is where my code fails

Comment: "Fail" is very imprecise.  The reading should work.  The remaining problems are that you only copy `templName` into your `people[0].name`, that you don't add a terminating null to it, and that by the way `[j]` instead of `[0]` could help ;-).  If you're not familiar with debuggers yet, don't hesitate to cout some intermediary results when it doesn't work like you want:  it often helps to better understand what's going on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `struct player` definition is not valid:

```
struct player {
    char name[];
    int total;
    card hand[];
};
```

The C string fields `name` and `hand` need to have a length, e.g.

```
struct player {
    char name[32];
    int total;
    card hand[32];
};
```

Your compiler should be giving you an error for this ("incomplete type").

Note also that since you are writing C++ code then it would be better to use `std::string` rather than C-style `char *` strings - it will be easier, more robust, and you won't be mixing C and C++ idioms.

Comment: i have to use c-style strings for this project, ill try initializing them with values. is this the only issue? does my loop look alright?

Comment: There are a few problems - @Christophe has covered some of them in his answer - fix the problems you know about first and then go round another compile/debug cycle to see what else needs fixing.

Comment: my core is still being dumped.. :(

Comment: You need to run your code under a debugger (e.g. gdb). Also make sure you compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) and *take notice of all warnings, and fix them*.